# SELECT DISTINCT only first four numbers

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the following table:

```
ticker  code
--------------
AA      151040
AAP     452020
DOW     151010
DVN     151020
EXC     452050
FAD     452070
POE     207010
```

I would like to select the tickers per code - but comparison has to be made on only the first four numbers of the code (so: 1510, 4520, 1510, etc), giving a result like:

```
1510 AA
1510 DOW
1510 DVN
4520 AAP
4520 EXC
4520 FAD
2070 POE
```

With what query can I take only the first four numbers?

Comment: Where does `DISTINCT` come into play?

Comment: I downvoted you because I'm tired to read this kind of question. What have search ? What have you try ? I never use MySQL and it took me a single query to google to find something to try. You don't know what is the function... Me Neither. But looking for `mysql`, `string` `function` gave me many hits...

Don't take it personnal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`LEFT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_left):

```
SELECT LEFT(code, 4) AS code, ticker FROM tbl ORDER BY code;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(code,1,5) AS SUB_CODE,ticker
FROM TABLE;
```

Comment: [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) is for aggregate functions. It won't do anything for this query.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Left function in mySql to select the first four Left(code,4) Then use order by.